# R NLS convergence issues

Tags: r

I am trying to fit some data using the R nls function, and am fairly new to this.  I keep getting issues where the algorithm will not converge, or when it does converge it converges to a bad fit. My data is lengthy and being read in from a csv but i have attatched a graph of the portion i am trying to fit.

Additionally this is the code that i am running.

```
urate <- 2600000
data <- data.frame(t(u[8,651:1250]))
data <- cbind(data, 1:600/urate)
colnames(data) <- c('V', 't')

fit <- nls(V ~ udmp(t, rf, dmp, phi, A, C), 
             data = data, 
             start = list(rf = 2742.148, dmp =3150, phi = 0, A = .8,C = -.8),
             lower = list( 2000, 3000, -pi, -2, -1), 
             upper = list(3500, 4000, pi, 2, 0),
             algorithm = 'port')


udmp <- function(t, rf, dmp, phi, A, C){
     A*exp(-dmp*t/2)*cos(rf*t + phi) + C
}
```

I have tried messing with the initial parameters, for example if i change phi to 1 in start, the algorithm converges but returns an almost straight line.  It seems as though the majority of starting parameters cause failure to converge and at this point im completely unsure why.  The starting values of rf and dmp are calculated from theoretical values and should be fairly close to the actual values in the final fit, and my starting values for A and C were eyeballed from the graph of the data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBhMk.png

Comment: This question is more about statistics than R code, so it would be better received on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular questions should have complete reproducible examples.  No one but you can run this since the input is missing.  If you drop the bound constraints you could use `algorithm = "plinear"` which does not require starting values for the 2 linear parameters reducing the problem to 3 nonlinear parameters.